# How to insert a value into a type date column of database?

Tags: java, mysql, date

How to save the value of a variable that is as a date to the database.

My String is as following

Java

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat parseFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        //SimpleDateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss+hh:mm"); 
        Date date = parseFormatter.parse(mydate);

        String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
        System.out.println("Date"+formattedDate);
      return formattedDate;  <<need to save its value to database lets say its value is 2013-03-19
```

I need to save it into a column of table that its type is date.

Database

```
Name Type
Date date
```

I suppose I need to convert the string to date but how?

```
ps.setDate(????)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if mydate is a string in yyyy-MM-dd format then you can do the following

```
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into t1 (date) values (?)");
    ps.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(mydate));
    ps.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function in MySql

**EDIT**

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO table (dateCol1, col2 ..)
VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('May 1, 2013','%M %d,%Y'), col2value, ...)
```

Comment: how to insert it to the table as a date?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL understands dates.  Assuming you are using a `PreparedStatement` you can just use standard JDBC `stmt.setDate(n,date)` where `n` is the parameter index and `date` is a Java variable of type date.

No need to do any string conversions.

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose I need to convert the string to date but how?

If you want to convert `String` into `Date`, suppose your `String` is `2013-03-19`

```
String yourString = "2013-03-19";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(yourString);
```

Here your `String` is converted into the `Date` object, but if you need to set this particular date into another date object then this is not possible in this way `yourDateObj.setDate(date)` because there is no any such direct method in Date class which will take date as an argument.

to set a particular date you can use  Calendar 
like

```
Calendar yourDate = new GregorianCalendar();
yourDate.setTime(date);
```

Other wise you can do this way also with `Date(int year, int month, int date)` but it is deprecated now.

Or If you wish to insert `String` into `Date` column of `mysql` then [#function_str-to-date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date),  I agree with **Ed Heal** answer